# Trouble with QList

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore, qlist

If I set a QList inside a function, it works properly

```
void MainWindow::ReadXML() {
    ...
    QList<QString> list;
    list << "alfa" << "beta" << "gamma" << "delta" << "epsilon";
    ...
}
```

But if try to write the same piece of code outside of a block (the QList must be visible to the whole file), Qt Creator underlines in red the last line tells and me this error: "expeted to declaration"

Any suggestion?

Comment: You can't put anything that's not a declaration in the global scope, and it's generally considered bad practice to even put declarations there.

Comment: And what would be the best way?

Comment: Most likely utilizing classes or function parameters and return values appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

You would have several ways to solve this issue, but here goes one of those:

```
static QStringList myStringList = QStringList << "foo" << "bar" << "baz";

void MainWindow::ReadXML() 
{
    ...
    useMyStringList(myStringList);
     ...
}
```

but it is bad practice to use static variables like that, so I would probably utilize C++ more, at the very least, I would create a function as follows:

```
static QStringList myStringList()
{
    static QStringList stringList = QStringList() << "foo" << "bar" << "baz";
    return stringList;
}


void MainWindow::ReadXML() 
{
    ...
    useMyStringList(myStringList());
     ...
}
```

1) Note that you could use QStringList instead of QList. It will have convenience methods available for you, and in general, it feels more natural.

2) With C++11 and on, you could use initializer list, so instead of writing:

```
QStringList myStringList = QStringList << "foo" << "bar" << "baz";
```

You could do this:

```
QStringList myStringList{"foo", "bar", "baz"};
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful information! Only one question: what is useMyStringList()?

Comment: @user3204810: it is whatever function you do. I just used this as a placeholder. Of course, you do not need it, if you deal with the string list inside the function without calling another one.

Comment: To preempt overeager comments: it's worth noting that any compiler worth its salt will, if not outright inlining the function, apply [NRVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) within `myStringList`, so returning by value is not any less efficient than returning by const reference (as in `static const QStringList & myStringList()`). It is entirely proper and idiomatic to return by value, as Laszlo suggests.